# The history of trigonometry in two old stories

Tags: trigonometry, math-history, mathematicians

There is a story, apparently from Diogenes Laertius and Plutarch (and repeated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales_of_Miletus#Engineering), and [here](https://www.psd1.org/cms/lib/WA01001055/Centricity/Domain/36/SS_Measuring_the_Great_Pyramid.pdf), and [here](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/maths-linear-quadratic-relations/0/steps/12094), and, well, [here](https://www.ask.com/web?o=0&l=dir&qo=serpSearchTopBox&q=Thales%20height%20of%20egyptian%20pyramids)) that Thales was able to calculate the height of an Egyptian pyramid by the following method: he waited until the length of his own shadow was equal to his height, and then measured the shadow of the pyramid. He reasoned that at that moment the pyramid will (like him) cast a shadow as long as its own height.

This story seems to occur at a fairly early stage in the consideration of the problem. Using only middle-school mathematics, and at any moment when the sun is in the sky, the man could measure his shadow, his own height, and the pyramid’s shadow, and then calculate the height of the pyramid by proportional reasoning; he need not wait until the sun angle makes his shadow's length equal to his own height. Using trig tables instead, the man need never measure his own shadow or height at all.

But they say that Archimedes was able to calculate the value of $\pi$ by comparing the perimeters of polygons drawn such that the radius of a single circle is the radius of the smaller polygon and the apothem of the larger polygon. When I try this latter problem, it involves me in trig tables.

Am I right – Archimedes used trig tables because they were introduced during the 400-year window between the two lives? Or is there another explanation for the stories, if trig tables existed at both times or at neither time? Perhaps in the story about the pyramid the difficulty about using trig tables was just the practical one, measuring the sun’s angle?

Comment: You don't _need_ trig tables to calculate the circumference of a regular 96-sided polygon, given its radius or its apothem. It helps, but it's not necessary. We wouldn't remember it as a great feat of Archimedes if all he did was using trig tables.

Comment: Archimedes was at the cusp of the invention of trigonometry, and perhaps had he not been struck down, may have made more significant developments there.  But, it seems that he had derived as much as half angle formulas to find the important ratios for a 12, 24, 48 and 96 sided polygon.  Most must of trig was developed after Archimedes death.

Comment: @Arthur I see that the radii of a 12-gon create triangles with angles 30, 75 and 75. If you then draw in the apothem to create right triangles, their angles are 15, 75 and 90. Without trig tables, what's the next step?

Comment: Before the trig tables, there was right triangles tables, listing most of the common right triangle (the 3-4-5 was known by the early egyptian and by babylonians as well).

Comment: @Martigan So can you explain how Archimedes proceeded? (1) He created the 15, 75, 90 triangles, in which he knew only radius=hypotenuse, or apothem=leg, but not both... Then what?

Comment: @Chaim The triangles of a 12, or 24 sided polygons were probably known by then, and thus you only need the scale to have the other lengths.

Comment: @Martigan So (1) he chose a radius for the circle, (2) considered it as the radius of one 24-gon and the apothem of a second 24-gon, (3) looked up on a table the related perimeters, (4) averaged those two perimeters, (5) divided the average by the square of the radius, and considered that quotient as his approximation of Pi. How was the table constructed?

Comment: @Martigan Actually at (5) in the previous comment I was thinking about average area. From the average circumference, you would not divide by the square of the radius, but rather by twice the radius, to find Pi.

Comment: In some sense, yes, Archimedes used trig tables. The same way you use $\arctan(1)$ to figure out that a right, isosceles triangle has angle $45^\circ$. Or the way you use $\sin(30^\circ)=\frac12$ when saying that the hypotenuse is twice the short leg in a 30-60-90 triangle, even though they actual argument is a bisected equilateral triangle. It might be more correct to say that he was _making_ the trig tables, though. At least for a few nice angles. I don't know exactly how he did it for 12-gon and up, but I would assume that that's what he did.

Comment: You might try out here too-https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Using the language of trigonometry it makes things easier to follow.  But Archimedes himself did not know trig.  But the extrapolation to classical geometry is not so difficult.

6 equilateral triangles can be put together to form a hexagon.

The sides of an inscribed hexagon are each of length $2\sin 30$
The sides of an excribed hexagon are each of length $2\tan 30$

$12\sin 30 \le 2\pi \le 12\tan 30$

$\tan 30 = \sqrt 3, \cos 30 = \frac {\sqrt 3}{2}, \sin 30 = \frac 12$

And if we had a formula to find $\sin \frac {\theta}{2}, \tan \frac \theta 2$ based on $\sin\theta, \cos\theta, \tan\theta$

then

$(2^n)6\sin \frac {30}{2^n} \le \pi \le (2^n)\tan \frac {30}{2^n}$

And we do:

$\tan \frac 12 \theta = \frac {\sin\theta}{1+\cos \theta}\\
\cos \frac 12 \theta = \frac {\sqrt {1+\cos \theta}}{2}\\
\sin \frac 12 \theta = \frac {\sqrt {1-\cos \theta}}{2}\\
$

We repeatedly apply the half angle theorems then we will get increasingly accurate bounds for $\pi$

But Archimedes did not have trig.  What tools did he have at his disposal?

[image]

If $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$ then $BD:DC = AB:AC$

From which we can derive:

$BD:DC = AB:AC\\
\frac {BD}{DC} = \frac {BC - DC}{DC} = \frac {BC}{DC} - 1\\
\frac {BC}{DC} = \frac {AB}{AC} + 1 = \frac {AB+AC}{AC}\\
\frac {DC}{AC} = \frac {BC}{AB+AC}$

Which is equivalent to the $\tan \frac 12 \theta$ formula above

It also seems that he used rational approximations of the trigonometric ratios at each step.  Exactly how he calculated those ratios has been lost over time, but methods to approximate square roots were known to the Babylonians, and certainly would have been known to Archimedes.

A 30-60-90 triangle has rations approximately:

$BC:AC:AB \approx 153:265:306$
\frac {DC}{AC} = \frac {153}{571}$

Using the Pythagorean theorem: $\sqrt {153^2 + 571^2}\approx 591$
$DC:AC:AD \approx 153:571:591$

$6\cdot \frac {153}{571}<\pi<6\frac {571}{591}\\
3<\pi<3.46$

Repeating the process gives us methods to approximate ratios for a sequence of right triangles each with an angle half the size of the one before.

If $E$ lies on the angle bisector of $DC$

$EC:AC:AD = 153:1162:1172$

$12\cdot \frac {153}{1162}<\pi<12\frac {153}{1172}\\
3.10<\pi<3.22$

etc.

Comment: I can't quite follow that. Is C a right angle? Is BC one half of one side of the original n-gon? Where did all of those numbers (153; 265; 306) come from? How do we reach the approximation of Pi from all of that?

Comment: Is this easier to follow?

Comment: The equation $\frac{BD}{DC} = \frac{AB}{AC} + 1$ contradicts the equation $BD : DC = AB : AC$.

Comment: Okay, now I follow up to the words "Using the Pythagorean Theorem". At that place, I assume that we knew the 153 from the 30-60-90 proportion, and we somehow knew the 571, and we used the Pythagorean Thm to find 591. How did we know the 571?

Comment: I thought that you were saying that the 30-60-90 side proportions were known somehow or other and were used to find the side proportions in a right triangle with one angle 30/2, then 30/4, then 30/8, etc.